# Value of a determinant

Tags: exponential-function, determinant

> Let $a_1 < a_2 < \ldots < a_n$ and $b_1 < b_2 < \ldots < b_n$ be read numbers. Let $A = (A_{ij})_{i,j=1}^n$ be the $n \times n$ matrix with $A_{ij} = e^{a_ib_j}$. How do I compute $\det A$?

I tried expansion using co-factors and then induction. For the base case, it is pretty clear, but then I do not know how to prove for the other cases.

Comment: Is this an exercise ? Because it might be difficult to get an expression of this determinant if there is any.

Comment: It would do, if I could just show if the value of the determinant is greater than or less than 0.